# Integrating $(1+|x|)^{-d-1}$ over $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How might one go about showing that the integral

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (1+|x|)^{-d-1}\,\,dx$$

converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polar coordinates:
$$\int_{\Bbb R^d}f(|x|)\,dx=C_d\int_0^\infty f(r)r^{d-1}\,dr$$
for a suitable constant $C_d$.